# One git repository, conditional root based upon sparse checkout

Tags: git

What I want to accomplish is this:

1 - **one** repository on my development machine and github (i.e. one remote)

2 - on my servers I want the root folders of the repository to contain the source code contained in *one* of the subdirectories of the repository

Assume this repository structure (on my dev machine)

```
/root # the actual git repository
  ./git  
  /sub-root1 # contains source code for sub-root1
    sub-file1
  /sub-root2 # contains source code for sub-root2
    sub-file2
```

Now, on my server I want to run

```
cd /var/sub-root1 && git pull git@github.com/root-repository.git
```

and **only** receive the source code for `sub-root1` (and vice verca for `sub-root2`), i.e. the following structure

```
/sub-root1 # system folder
  ./git
  sub-file1
```

I have managed to obtain the following structure with **sparse checkout**:

```
/sub-root1 # system folder
  /.git
  /sub-root1 # git folder
    sub-file1
```

I realise that moving the `sub-root` folders up as root folders would mean making the repository dirty, but I was hoping there was some elegant way of handling this (my best current idea is to use `mv` in a post-receive hook).

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [git submodules](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)? This way you can define `sub-root1` and `sub-root2` as submodules. For more details you can use the [GitSubmoduleTutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial)

Comment: We eventually moved away from the architecture I detailed in the question, so I didn't have time to look into submodules, but I'll assume that they could've solved the problem :-)